# Android push notification opening is not counting when customize the notification builder

Tags: mobilepush-android

I have an app set up for Android, and it's working well except for 1 thing,when I override and customize  the notification builder, the android app is not counting when the user opens the notification, then MarketingCloud does not take that into the % of opens.

Is there an specific setup that we need to do, or an specific line that I might have missed on the docs that does the trick?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code from your NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder implementation?

Comment: Please check my my question soon @@
Thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my question below :D

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the code.  There are a couple issues here.

1. Your implementation of the `NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder` interface should not display the notification itself.  This will be done be the SDK using the returned `NotificationCompat.Builder` from the `setupNotificationBuilder` method.
2. If `DisplayMessageActivity` is the only Activity you use for notification clicks then you can just set it with `setNotificationRecipient` in the `MarketingCloudConfig`.  If your application has custom logic to determine which Activity should be used based on the incoming message then you can implement the `NotificationManager.NotificationLaunchIntentProvider` and return a different destination based on the `NotificationMessage`.  The SDK will use either of these to set the contentIntent on the notification builder that is returned in `setupNotificationBuilder`.

Comment: Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Dear @Seth here is my code :

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements NotificationManager.NotificationBuilder{
  public void onCreate() {

```
 //init
 MarketingCloudSdk.init(this, MarketingCloudConfig.builder().setApplicationId(Utils.SL_APP_ID)
            .setAccessToken(Utils.SL_ACCESS_TOKEN)
            .setGcmSenderId(Utils.SENDER_ID)
            .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
            .setNotificationBuilder(this)
            .build(), this);
```

}

```
@Override
public NotificationCompat.Builder setupNotificationBuilder(final @NonNull Context context, @NonNull NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

Intent  resultIntent = new Intent(context, DialogMessageActivity.class);

   ...              
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationBuilder.build());                     

 return notificationBuilder ;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!
And in the other case, when I want to display a message dialog instead of notification view in case of apps is in the foreground (apps is opening). In this case, the notification can not be analyzed, is it?
I desire a public method which can analytics the notification bundle content  anywhere, is it possible?

Comment: @Seth: do you have any solution for my case?